# Is density of states some kind of degeneracy?

Tags: solid-state-physics

Is density of states some kind of degeneracy? If so, then what is the corresponding symmetry hidden behind? If density of states does not relate to degeneracy, the how to understand that there're states of the same energy?

Comment: Not necessarily: when the energy levels are close together and you can approximate them as a continuum, then the density of states allows you to turn sums into integrals. It is basically just the integration measure (in the mathematical sense).The levels may or may not be degenerate and if they are, you have to account for that (either separately or by incorporating the degeneracy into the measure).